# Listing the books in the archives of the Temple of Ganesh

Tags: comics, ursula-vernon, digger

*Digger* is a webcomic about a wombat. On the comic published on April 12th, 2007, we're shown the archives of the Temple of Ganesh. [You can view the comic online](http://diggercomic.com/blog/2007/04/12/digger-64/). Looking at the archives, several of the books in the archives have visible titles.

Is there a list of all the books whose titles are visible? I tried googling "digger archives of temple of ganesh" but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't know of any existing list, so I made my own. (?) means it's my best read but I think I'm probably wrong.

> *Leviticu<sup>2</sup>* (?)
>   *Rats I Have Known
>
>   Black Dogs
>
>   King in Yellow
>
>   Chickens IV
>
>   Squids
>
>   Alice in Wonder Land
>
>   Chickens of the World II
>
>   Shmoops* (?)
>   *I Am Mouse
>
>   Sandman
>
>   Rlyeh Text III
>
>   Nobel
>
>   Chicken II
>
>   Abridged History of the Cosmos–the First 50 Years* (this one was tricky, but [Vernon had already told us what it says](http://www.redwombatstudio.com/2004/02/12/556/).)

And four pages later we see:

> *No Bad Frogs
>
>   Guide to Man*

Looks like there's a D&D manual on the shelf in that panel too.

The rest of the titles in the chapter are either partials (*Note-* and *Smo-*), gibberish, or easy to make out (*Atlas*, *Squid*). Mention to *Travels and Travails* though, and *Travel [illegible] on the Sou* (or *Son*?).

Comment: I like that there are multiple books about chickens.